# Generating XSD from XML and add namespace XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, soap, xsd

I need your help with this XML ---> XSD generation + adding a namespace to it.
I will explain more.

[XML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dyeCi.png)
(This is code in case you want to copy it for your reply...)

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                  xmlns:urn="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" 
                  xmlns:urn1="urn:sobject.enterprise.soap.sforce.com" 
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

 <urn:update>
     <urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:Account">
       <urn1:Id>001b0000006mKKqAAM</urn1:Id>
       <!--You may enter ANY elements at this point-->
       <AnnualRevenue>9988</AnnualRevenue>
       <Name>Farell Instruments WYNSYS</Name>
    </urn:sObjects>
 </urn:update>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

[XSD](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDXni.png)
(This is code in case you want to copy it for your reply...)

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified"    
           targetNamespace="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" 
           xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="update">
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="sObjects">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Id"/>
          <xs:element type="xs:string" name="Name"/>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute type="xs:string" name="type"/>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

My requirement now is to pass the attribute with the type Account just like this :
        urn:sObjects xsi:type="urn1:Account"

but using XSD, I think that I need to use XSD mapping in order to do this ! 
I am totaly lost I tried several formats but still dont get the right one.

Any idea please how to get the exact XSD format for the XML ?

Thanks.
BR,
Mohamed Amine.

Comment: Sorry, I do not get what you want. Do you want to express with schema that `xsi:type` attribute always have the value `urn1:Account`? Or that if type attribute is given it needs to match a type specified with schema?

Comment: This is the XML which is sent during the WS Call :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:update xmlns:ns2="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
<ns2:sObjects type="Account">
<ns2:Id>001b0000006mKKqAAM</ns2:Id>
<ns2:Name>NewName</ns2:Name>
</ns2:sObjects>
</ns2:update>

The problem is here : <ns2:sObjects type="Account">, it should be something like this <ns2:sObjects xsi:type="Account">

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XSD schema-validation uses a built-in definition of the `xsi:type` attribute; it is not possible to specify in a schema that it must have a particular value or to constrain its value beyond the constraints imposed by the XSD spec.

If you are trying to write an XSD schema that constrains the value of xsi:type, then, you can stop trying now and look for a different solution to your problem.  If you're not trying to do that, then you need to try again to explain what it is you are trying to do; it's not clear from the question.

Comment: Indeed I stopped trying, it's a real dead-end ! thanks.
I turned to XSLT to try to change the value.
please check this : 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37007562/xslt-replace-attribute-and-its-value