# XSLT replace attribute and its value

Tags: xml, xslt

I have this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:update xmlns:ns2="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
  <ns2:sObjects type="Account">
    <ns2:Id>001b0000006mKKqAAM</ns2:Id>
    <ns2:Name>NewName</ns2:Name>
  </ns2:sObjects>
</ns2:update>
```

And I want to have this output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:update xmlns:ns2="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
  <ns2:sObjects xsi:type="Account" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <ns2:Id>001b0000006mKKqAAM</ns2:Id>
    <ns2:Name>NewName</ns2:Name>
  </ns2:sObjects>
</ns2:update>
```

I need to change the attribute `type="Account"` to `xsi:type="Account"` with the namespace `xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"` in the `ns2:sObjects` element.

How can I do this using XSLT ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fiddled around with this a bit, is this what you are looking for?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:ns2="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <ns2:update xmlns:ns2="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
            <ns2:sObjects xsi:type="Account" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <ns2:Id><xsl:value-of select="/ns2:update/ns2:sObjects/ns2:Id"/></ns2:Id>
                <ns2:Name><xsl:value-of select="/ns2:update/ns2:sObjects/ns2:Name"/></ns2:Name>
            </ns2:sObjects></ns2:update>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It updates the attribute of sObjects and gets the child `Id` and `Name` nodes

output (using your input)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns2:update xmlns:ns2="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
    <ns2:sObjects xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Account">
        <ns2:Id>001b0000006mKKqAAM</ns2:Id>
        <ns2:Name>NewName</ns2:Name>
    </ns2:sObjects>
</ns2:update>
```

Comment: The `xmlns:xml` and `xsi:type` attributes are flipped around, but normally, that wouldn't make a difference either

Answer (score 0):

Add a template like the following to an identity transform:

```
<xsl:template match="@type[. = 'Account']">
  <xsl:attribute name="xsi:type" 
    namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <xsl:value-of select="'Account'"/>
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

If the term "identity transform" says nothing to you, a web search engine should help.

Comment: Yes this is exactly what I am looking for ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

A very simple XSLT stylesheet to achieve this would be

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns2="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xsl:output method="xml" />

  <!-- Identity template -->
  <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template> 

  <!-- replaces the ns2:sObjects node with the replacement -->
  <xsl:template match="ns2:sObjects">
    <ns2:sObjects xsi:type="{@type}">
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </ns2:sObjects>
  </xsl:template> 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Its output is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<ns2:update xmlns:ns2="urn:enterprise.soap.sforce.com">
  <ns2:sObjects xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="Account">
    <ns2:Id>001b0000006mKKqAAM</ns2:Id>
    <ns2:Name>NewName</ns2:Name>
  </ns2:sObjects>
</ns2:update>
```